# sorting by value in another table php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have two tables, one called episodes, and one called score. The episode table has the following columns:

> id | number | title | description | type

The score table has the following columns:

> id | userId | showId | score

The idea is that users will rate a show. Each time a user rates a show, a new row is created in the score table (or updated if it exists already). When I list the shows, I average all the scores for that show ID and display it next to the show name.

What I need to be able to do is sort the shows based on their average rating. I've looked at joining the tables, but haven't really figured it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To order the results, use and `ORDER BY` clause. You can order by generated columns, such as the result of an aggregate function like `AVG`.

```
SELECT e.title, AVG(s.score) AS avg_score
  FROM episodes AS e
    LEFT JOIN scores AS s ON e.id=s.showId
  GROUP BY e.id
  ORDER BY avg_score DESC;
```

Comment: This is returning results correctly, but it's not ordering them at all. The order is the same as the order of the rows in the table.

Comment: Got it working. Not sure what I did to make it work though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're right. You have to JOIN these tables, then use GROUP BY on the 'episodes' table's 'id' column. Then you'll be able to use AVG() function on 'the scores' tables's 'score' column.

```
SELECT AVG(scores.score) FROM episodes LEFT JOIN scores ON scores.showId = episodes.id GROUP BY episodes.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT episodes.*, AVG(score.score) as AverageRating FROM episodes
INNER JOIN score ON (episodes.id = score.showId)
GROUP BY episodes.id
ORDER BY AVG(score.score) DESC
```

Comment: This isn't working. I get blank space where my while loop sits.

Comment: I tested it with a copy of your tables, in MySQL query browser, it works.